# Is the Mining Helmet worth it in Terraria?

Tags: terraria-console

In Terraria on console, the merchant can sell you the [Mining Helmet](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Mining_Helmet) for 8 gold. Is it worth farming gold to obtain the helmet, considering my primary objective is to farm ore?

Or is there a more suitable/efficient method to keep me illuminated/safe while I mine?

Comment: I would like to point out that by the time you can afford the mining helmet, unless you killed a pinky or something, you probably have better armor.

Comment: @Gamer3001, if you read the question, I make no relation to using the helmet as armor. I was more concerned with lighting dark passages. I also had the gold fairly quickly (I killed a pinky, but it did not drop much, perhaps you meant to imply killing a pinky and getting lucky on the gold drop?) so I ultimately did purchase the mining helmet, and found it very useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on your priorities and current equipment.

First let's consider the alternatives.

- Torches
- Light Pets
- Shine Potion

The good thing about the Mining helmet is that it will allow you to see everything around you constantly, without the need of placing torches every time you settle somewhere. The problem is that in early game the lack of defense can be problematic, specially in biomes with a lot of monsters. If you, on the other hand, have good enough equipment, the lack of defense won't be that much of a problem and the helmet will be great.

Having said that you can also consider crafting shine potions, which require Daybloom and Glowing Mushrooms. However to make this a viable long term option you will need two small Daybloom and Glowing Mushrooms farms, to maintain your stock of ingredients.

Finally the light pets are a possibility, but in the early game they're quite lacking, as the light they provide is not much.

Personally I prefer using torches. If you plan on going hardmode on that specific world, they're only a small investment of time, given that you will be constantly using the tunnels you dug before.

Answer (score 1):

Well yes and no. Yes because you won't need to waste your wood and gel, but no because it will only glow if equipped, and armor in the vanity slots does nothing.  So have good weapons or an escape route, because if you don't, then no - it is a waste of gold.

Comment: "Waste"?  Gel?!?  Other than stacks of Dirt, Gel is one of the few things in the game that you collect *far* faster than you use.

Comment: @tjd Only if you have a slime farm. In the early game, it's easy to use up stacks of torches like no tomorrow when exploring.

Comment: @mbomb007, One does use up stacks of torches when exploring.  One also meets slimes galore in most biomes.  I suppose if you actively *run* from slimes while exploring you could, conceivably, run low.  I find keeping up with the wood demands of my torch placing far more of a burden.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the mining helmet helps a lot. Go to the ice biome after and kill undead miners. Their clothes and helmet give a great mining speed buffs. I use these with shroomite digging claws when I go mining and it saves a ton of time.

Comment: Sorry, I will work on that.

Answer (score -1):

Lighting is and has always been one of the biggest things you're worried about when mining, needless to say, a mining helmet would be extremely useful. BUT, due to the mining helmet actually being really useful in lightning, the defence of it is the same of a wood helmet, absolutely awful.
I wouldn't recommend using a mining helmet, after finding new ores or beating the second boss in the game you'll outmatch its defense by tons (and defense is probably the most important stat of the game in general), so no, if you do buy it you'll switch it out after an hour or two of playtime anyways.